# Android - How to choose the right animation class?

Tags: java, android, animation

Assuming you have some experience with Android animations, you probably know that there are many ways to create an animation in Android, so many that it gets confusing!

Currently I'm developing a game that has about 100 different objects on the screen that need to be animated at all times, a task - that as I understand it - may cost lots of CPU.

So, my questions are:

1. What is the best Animation class to use in a case like this?
2. What will be the right approach to go about that?

NOTE: THE ANIMATED OBJECTS PARAMETERS MUST TO BE CONTROLLED AND CHANGED FROM JAVA AT RUN TIME, SO XML ANIMATION IS NOT A SUITABLE SOLUTION.

Any code snippets will be very much appreciated!!